# Assuming the two people wait for each other, what is the expected waiting time?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Two people agree to meet at a restaurant. Assume their arrival times are independent
and uniformly distributed on the one hour interval from 1:00–2:00 p.m. Assuming the two people wait for each other, what is the expected
waiting time?

$\textbf{Hint}$: Let X be the arrival time of one person and Y the arrival time of the other
person. Express the event of interest in terms of X and Y . S

I think the expected time of waiting should be 0 right? Since it's a uniform distribution, then EX = 30 and EY = 30. Therefore E(X-Y) = 0.

What do you guys think?

Comment: You actually want to compute $E(|X-Y|)$.

Comment: Be careful... Waiting time is $|X-Y|$, not $X-Y$. Hint: try conditioning on $Y$...

Comment: Thanks for your replies! If I condition on Y, then it means that E(|X-Y|) = E(X-Y| Y comes first) + E(Y-X| Y does not come first) right? But how does this change the solution? Shouldn't both these expected values be 0?

Comment: When did you last meet someone at a restaurant and wait 0 minutes for them to arrive (on average)?

Answer (score 1):

Because the joint distribution is so simple:  $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1, \quad 0 \le x, y \le 1,$$ it is easier to integrate directly:  $$\operatorname{E}[|X-Y|] = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 |x-y| f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^x x-y \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x}^1 y-x \, dy \, dx.$$

Comment: What  is  the  exact  answer  of  this  question ?  Is  it  10  minutes  ?

Comment: @mrwong No.  There are two double integrals, each of which has value $1/6$, so the expectation is $1/3$ (of an hour); i.e., $20$ minutes.

Comment: Thanks  for  your  reply !  But  I  am  a  bit  doubtful  of  your  answer . 
The  question  does  not  state  how  long  the  2  people  will  wait  for  each  other . I  assume  that  they  will  wait   as  long  as  possible  , i.e. 
60  minutes  at  maximum . I  obtained  an  answer  of  10  minutes  for  either  one  of  them . Will  you  mean   that  20  minutes  is  for  their  total   expected  waiting  time ?

Comment: I  think  I  have  got  the  point . Both  of  us  are  right . You  may  mean  
that  the  expected  waiting  time  of  the  early  comer  is  20  minutes  . 
Since  there  is  1/2  chance  for  either  one  of  them  to  be  early  comer  
and  1/2  chance  to  be  late  comer , with  expected  waiting  time  to  be  
0 minute . Thus  the  expected  waiting  time  for  any  one  of  them  will  
be  1/2 * 20 min + 1/2 * 0 min = 10 min .  Thanks  again !